# Forgot to type ; at end of mysql statement, how to go back?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How do I recover from the below?  I need to get back to the maria prompt, i've tried exit and quit neither work.  Currently just using ctrl-c which required me to log back in to mysql.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> DROP DATABASE drupal_db
    ->
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get back" - if you simply forgot to add the semicolon at the end just input the semicolon at the prompt in the next line and hit enter, that should do it. But maybe I am getting this wrong?

Comment: Is your intention to avoid accidentally dropping the `drupal_db` database?  Or do you want to do something else?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with \c
It will move your cli to previous state

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to have the ; on the same line as your command so you can just put it on the next line by itself.
If you find in some place you've made an error like dropping a single or double quote you can use \c to exit to the next line of the shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Your only option is to end the query and [Ctrl]+[C] out.

See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/entering-queries.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
'> 'c/
-> ;
```

I just learned from above me name cctan. thanks.